# Redirect '/*' without origin in Azure Front Door

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-front-door

I have setup `my.domain.com/sv` and `my.domain.com/en` in Azure Front Door. Now I want to create a rule to redirect from `/*` to the correct path depending on `Accept-Language`. However, to create a route (that I need to be able to assign the rule to a route) I seem to need an origin group with an origin. Is it possible to create an "empty" route somehow or create the redirect some other way? Or should I just assign `google.com` or a dummy value to `hostName` to be able to create the route?

My attempt to create a default route using bicep:

```
resource profile 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2021-06-01' = {
  name: profileName
  location: 'global'
  sku: {
    name: skuName
  }
}

resource endpoint 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints@2021-06-01' = {
  name: 'org-fde-${shortAppName}'
  parent: profile
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    enabledState: 'Enabled'
    autoGeneratedDomainNameLabelScope: 'ResourceGroupReuse'
  }
}

resource defaultOriginGroup 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/originGroups@2021-06-01' = {
  name: 'default-origin-group'
  parent: profile
  properties: {
    loadBalancingSettings: {}
  }

  resource defaultOrigin 'origins' = {
    name: 'default-origin'
    properties: {
      hostName: '/' <-- INVALID
    }
  }
}

resource defaultRoute 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/afdEndpoints/routes@2021-06-01' = {
  name: 'default-route'
  parent: endpoint
  dependsOn:[
    defaultOriginGroup::defaultOrigin // This explicit dependency is required to ensure that the origin group is not empty when the route is created.
  ]
  properties: {
    originGroup: {
      id: defaultOriginGroup.id
    }
    ruleSets: []
    supportedProtocols: [
      'Http'
      'Https'
    ]
    patternsToMatch: [
      '/*'
    ]
    forwardingProtocol: 'HttpsOnly'
    linkToDefaultDomain: 'Enabled'
    httpsRedirect: 'Enabled'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a best practice you should create your origin group with a single origin back to `my.domain.com`.  That will allow you to create your redirection rule and would make sense to anyone else looking at the configuration.